# Android Virtual Device state is offline after saving to snapshot and starting again

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, android-virtual-device

I've seen a couple of similar problems on SO, but none of the solutions has worked for me.

Until a couple of weeks ago, saving / starting Android Virtual Devices from snapshot worked perfectly, but not any more. I have an AVD that works the first time I start it up, but, when I close the window and start it a second time, the state is "offline" and the target platform is "unknown".

Restarting adb doesn't help, and neither does restarting Eclipse. I can wipe the user data and it will work, but then I have the same problem the next time I start it.

I could wipe the user data every time, and not use snapshots, but loading up the emulator from scratch is very slow.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I didn't. I just went ahead and bought physical devices for the major Android releases. It works a lot better, but does require a chunk of money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a long break from Android development, I started again. I've been using Android Studio for a while and I haven't had any issues like this. If you're using Eclipse and are having this issue, try switching to Android Studio and see if that helps.